# Pull all the arrays from the users matched by the criteria

Tags: mongodb

I have an annoying problem, and it is that even if the criteria matches several users in my system, just one of them has the specific array pulled.

This is how a user might look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ff696cf246951c8cea8506c"),
    "campaigns" : [
        {
            "userchannel" : 1,
            "id" : ObjectId("4ff59640acf479392600015b"),
            "name" : "test3"
        }
    ],
}
```

One user can have several campaigns, but only one with the same name. When I delete the campaign I want to update the users to the users containing this campaign are deleted. Only the users with a campaign containing `userchannel : 1` should be deleted.

I currently use this:

```
db.users.update({'campaigns.userchannel' : 1}, {$pull : {'campaigns' : {'id': ObjectId("4ff59640acf479392600015b")}}})
```

But it only deletes the campaign for one user. How can I improve this query so it deletes the specific campaign from all the users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a single update. The default behaviour for MongoDB updates is to only modify the first document that matches the criteria rather than for all matching documents as is common in RDBMS.

updates have the signature `update(criteria, update, upsert, multiple)`. The last parameter is a boolean that tells MongoDB to update all matching documents rather than the first.

Change your update to :

```
db.users.update({'campaigns.userchannel' : 1}, {$pull : {'campaigns' : {'id': ObjectId("4ff59640acf479392600015b")}}}, false, true)
```

Comment: I've got a problem when I'm trying to implement the solution: `
Warning: MongoCollection::update() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given in /application/models/Campaigns.php on line 59`. It seems like it don't like the 4th parameter.. :(

Comment: Nvm, php had an array to declare extra options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

Answer (score 1):

```
db.users.update({"campaigns.userchannel" : 1}, {$pull : {"campaigns" : {"id": ObjectId("4ff59640acf479392600015b")}}},false,true)
```

3rd parameter for upsert 
and
4th parameter for multi.
So you need to set multi to true